# How can I pass Deserialized JSON object from PCL to ViewController?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have an asynchronous method in my PCL which is retrieving and deserializing a JSON object. Once it has finished I would like to pass the object to my ViewController where is will be used to update the UI.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, testUrl);

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

string dataString = readStream.ReadToEnd();

var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(dataString);
```

What is the best pattern / best practice to achieve this in Xamarin?

Comment: `return json;`?

Comment: try to add HttpClient Library from nuget and discover all functions on this

Comment: You could also `ReadAsStringAsync` and pass that to JSON.NET and completely bypass the Stream code.